# ngMaterial and ngRoute Together Break App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I followed a tutorial on AngularJS and another tutorial on Angular Material. I wanted to now use Angular Material on my AngularJS project.

However, I found once I added 'ngMaterial' to the dependencies the app breaks. I am using Brackets as well to watch it live, and sure enough every time I click save after adding 'ngMaterial' it breaks. I tried altering when I inject it as well as changing the load order in the HTML file.

Below is the code for the HTML, app.js and controller.js. I appreciate any guidance!

--EDIT--
I added the console error as requested below. Please note if I remove ngMaterial from my app.js then there are no console errors.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Angular Material</title>
<!-- MATERIAL STYLESHEET -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css"> 

<!-- AngularJS Libraries -->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>


<!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<!-- ICON SET -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material-icons/0.7.1/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main" ng-view>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngRoute',
    'artistControllers'

  ]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', //The actual library link
    controller: 'ListController'
  }).
  when('/details/:itemId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
    controller: 'DetailsController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', ['ngAnimate']); 

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
  });
}]);

artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId; //$routeParams looks at the parameters in when (). In This case it's when on details:ItemId in the app.js file. Specifies which page to route to on a click.

    //Slider
    if ( $routeParams.itemId > 0 ){
        $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1; //Need number so it doesn't become string
    }else{
        $scope.prevItem = $scope.artists.length-1;
    }

    if ( $routeParams.itemId < $scope.artists.length-1 ){
        $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
    }else{
        $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }

  });
}]);
```

**CONSOLE ERROR**

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…%2Flocalhost%2Fangularmaterial%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A232)
    at http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:449
    at http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30:1
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:7:274)
    at e (http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:29:115)
    at $b (http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:32:232)
    at c (http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:17:431)
    at Zb (http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:18:140)
    at Tc (http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:17:215)
    at http://localhost/angularmaterial/lib/angular/angular.min.js:201:117
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:30
q @ angular.min.js:7
e @ angular.min.js:29
$b @ angular.min.js:32
c @ angular.min.js:17
Zb @ angular.min.js:18
Tc @ angular.min.js:17
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:201
a @ angular.min.js:131
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:27
q @ angular.min.js:7
c @ angular.min.js:27
```

Comment: Can you show us what happens when adding `ngMaterial` (like console errors, etc.)

Comment: Sure, I added the console error to my original question. It breaks the app by giving a completely blank screen as index.html no longer loads.

Comment: Try changing the order of your scripts in your **HTML**. It's currently loading `js/app.js` then `js/controllers.js"`. Load **controllers before app** and tell us if this changes something.

Comment: I just swapped the order putting js/controllers.js above js/app.js. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are misisng the reference for **`angular-aria.js`**, have it in the following order,

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.8.3/angular-material.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.8.3/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qwvS0gqV34yeKv6ixw4T?p=info)**

Comment: This is correct. I did not know angular-route.js was dependent on angular-aria.js if using Angular Material. When I originally did this tutorial without material, angular-aria was not used. I do know Angular Material uses angular-aria but the app worked without it before I added angular-route. If you know the reasoning, I'd love to learn more! Thank you for your help.